# Which standard must Li-ion battery fulfil for CE marking in late 2020, IEC 62133:2012 or IEC 62133-2:2017?

Tags: lithium-ion, certification, ce, regulations

I am looking for a slim CE-certified rechargable battery to put in my product. All of the (very few) certified batteries that I have found are compliant with the IEC 62133:2012 (2nd edition). [But that standard is withdrawn](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/6515) since, I believe, March 2020, and is replaced by IEC 62133-2:2017 (for lithium cells and batteries).

Does anybody have any experience in bringing a product with Li-ion battery through CE certification after the withdrawal of IEC 62133:2012?

Is it still somehow allowed to use batteries that are certified according to the withdrawn standard, or is it mandatory to have batteries certified to the new one?

During my search for appropriate batteries I realised that the standard procedure is to pay the battery maker to certify a custom pack for you. But that is not a viable option for the low quantities that I need.

I know that the UN38.3 must be fulfilled as well, but that seems to be less of a problem in my situation.

Comment: I wouldn't use an online forum to find an answer to that question, because it depends on your product - and many other factors. There are engingeering consultants who can help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

I am no specialist for batteries, but after a quick query at DIN

at least I would consider these 4

- IEC 61959:2004
- IEC 61960-3:2017
- IEC 62133-2:2017
- IEC 21A/690/CD:2018

EDIT: IEC standards only apply if they are 1:1 equal to EN standards. CE is European, so the EN standards apply.

https://www.cen.eu/Pages/default.aspx

https://www.cenelec.eu/

Comment: You can also have a look at this standard, depending on your application: IEC 62619:2017

Comment: Thank you both for your informative replies. This sure is a jungle..

The most commonly fulfilled standards seems to be IEC 62133. But I don't know which directive points where. So it might depend on what kind of product one is developing.

I am still hoping for someone that acually brought a product through certification this year to answer :)

Comment: Hi, just a quick comment if this thread is still relevant. You may require electrical safety for your product (BTW you don't mention this - what type of product ?) and this may be covered by En62368 (replacing En60950 since 12/2020). In the En62368 it is mentioned that IEC62133 or UL2054 or UL1973 are acceptable. In this case you should be looking at IEC62133 for your battery pack. Hope this helps ...